# Qt JSON internal program communication overhead

Tags: json, performance, qt

I have a client program that will receive a set of JSON instructions from a server. I think I have two options:

1) Split apart the JSON document, and send relevant parts to the different modules in the program

2) Split apart the JSON document, figure out what commands to call in the module, and call the commands

I feel 1) would be neater, as all the module processing happens inside the actual module. The only issue is including QJsonObject in all the modules, whereas 2 would only need it once. Does this cause an overhead or performance hit to the program compared with that of 2?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't be too worried about the overhead in splitting the JSON and processing it in different modules. What would worry me is if the communication protocol, for some reason in the future, may be changed to something else, such as XML.

If you've gone with your 2nd option, you'd then have to go through each module and make relevant changes. Personally, I'd opt for your 1st option. JSON is just the external language used for communication between the client and server.